# Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction in spring_Hibernate_Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have a requirement in my spring application where one of the methods receives concurrent requests for bulk inserting anything between 10000-50000 rows each into a table A(and another table B which has foreign key reference to A).I am using Hibernate for the same.While processing, I'm getting "Lock wait time out exceeded" exception.Have searched a lot but couldn't figure out how to solve this.The under lying database is MySQL.I have attached the same code below.Please help.

```
 SessionFactory sessionFactory = hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            for (i = 0; i < 50000 , i++) {
                a = new A();
                session.save(a);
                recordCounter++;
                if ((recordCounter % 20) == 0) {
                    session.flush();
                    session.clear();
                }
                if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
                    for (Object object : list) {
                        b = new B();
  //Setters
                        b.setA(a);
                        session.save(b);
                        dataCounter++;
                        if ((dataCounter % 20) == 0) {
                            session.flush();
                            session.clear();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception he) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception - ", he);
            transaction.rollback();
            throw he;

        } finally {
            if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
```

Logs :-

```
2013-07-02 12:41:46,932 [addVersionToFullData] ERROR   QueueHelper - Exception -
        org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [A]
        at    org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:40)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2158)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2638)
        at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:48)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:250)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:298)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:187)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:33)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:172)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:535)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:523)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:519)
        at com.manager.QueueHelper.populateSPInput(QueueHelper.java:1341)
        at com.manager.QueueHelper.addVersionToFullData(QueueHelper.java:1202)
        at com.manager.SyncServiceImpl.sendFullData(SyncServiceImpl.java:424)
        at com.controller.SynchronizationController.getFullData(SynchronizationController.java:434)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.invokeNamedMethod(MultiActionController.java:471)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.handleRequestInternal(MultiActionController.java:408)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
        Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3593)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3525)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1986)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2140)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2626)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2111)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2407)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2325)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2310)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:477)
        at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:33)
        ... 49 more
```

Comment: You will need to increase timeout OR use transactions with little chunks of data.

Answer (score 3):

Problem: You have this large transaction that is locking these rows.  When another request comes along, it has to wait for them to be unlocked.  Since the transaction is so large, it ends up waiting a really long time and timing out.

Solution:  If you really need this entire transaction to be atomic, then you need to increase the amount of time it will wait before timing out.  If you can stand to, it would probably be better to split it up into smaller transactions.